# Условные конструкции и цикл

Tags: python-3.x

> Имею пять списков значений
>
> Количество значений в каждом списке:

```
up_bar - 79
high_vl - 45
avg_sp - 11
up_cl - 44
max_cl - 22
```

> Если четыре значения из списков совпадают
>
> На экране выводится сообщение
>
> Пока запускается бесконечный цикл или при добавлении  == True ничего не выводит
>
> Подскажите что делаю неправильно?
>
> И как реализовать если можно при постоянно обновляющихся данных в списках?

```
while up_bar and high_vl and avg_sp and (up_cl or max_cl):
    print('str_a')
```

Comment: что значит 4 значения из списков совпадают? Приведите пример.

Comment: я так понимаю что цикл должен сработать 11 раз, т.к. все значения были вместе, а если хотя бы одного значения нет из 4 списков, то условие не выполнится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно определить количество итераций заранее, на основании размеров списков:

```
minLen = min(len(up_bar), len(high_vl), len(avg_sp), max(len(max_cl), len(up_cl)))
for i in range(0, minLen):
  print(up_bar[i]) // etc
```